# Send local mail to external SMTP in Exchange on SBS 2007

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I've got an SBS site and we're migrating from POP to exchange.

I can't migrate the users in one fell swoop, it's too difficult, so I want Outlook to pick up mail via POP, deliver it to the Exchange account, and send it from the exchange account. Eventually I'll replace the mx records and cancel the POP accounts.

As I can't migrate all users at once, I need exchange hub transport to send local mail to the external mx servers for delivery to the external pop accounts. At the moment it sends local mail to the internal Exchange account which not every internal user has access too yet.

How do I configure this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

We just did this very thing for a Customer a couple of weeks ago.

You can use Outlook or the Microsoft-provided POP3 Connector for Exchange 2007 to perform the retrieval of email (we used the POP3 connector). That's the easy bit. I'd use the server-side POP3 connector so that, when it's time to get rid of POP3, you can do that strictly server-side. That also prevents the user from screwing up their POP3 password and creating a support call.

Your Exchange 2007 server isn't authoritative for your email domain, since there's an another SMTP server where other recipients in that domain exist (the one at the ISP where the not-yet-migrated user accounts live). As such, you need to configure your domain as an [Internal Relay domain](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2008/09/25/how-to-configure-non-authoritative-accepted-domains-in-sbs-2008-exchange-2007.aspx). This tells Exchange that it's not authoritative for the domain, and causes it to deliver any messages that have unresolved recipients in that domain (which gets those messages delivered to your ISP (for the not-yet-migrated users).

Comment: OK, that sounds very close to what I want, except for the following difficulty:
All the users are already created in the domain, cause they're using other domain services. It's just e-mail we're now adding to the internal services. So I need exchange to deliver e-mail for all users to the external server.

Comment: What I've done so far:
I've set the users to use POP as the default, but deliver mail to the Exchange folders. When I've finished migrating all users, I'll change the MX records. When that's done, I'll run through and delete the POP accounts on the user's computers.

It's a bit extra work but there'll be no downtime.